# Segmentation fault and huge SRAM need for Serial.println

Tags: serial, programming, arduino-nano, class, c-preprocessor

I have written my own 'assert' since I want to use it for both Windows and Arduino. The class is called from many files (about 10).

AssertUtils.h:

```
#pragma once

#define assert(expr) AssertUtils::Assert2((expr), (__func__), (__FILE__), (__LINE__));

class AssertUtils
{
public:
    static void Assert2(bool expression, const char* funcName, const char* fileName, int line);
};
```

AssertUtils.cpp:

```
#include "AssertUtils.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

/* static */ void AssertUtils::Assert2(bool expression, const char* funcName, const char* fileName, int line)
{
    if (!expression)
    {
        Serial.println(funcName);
        Serial.println(fileName);
        Serial.println(line, DEC);
        Serial.flush();

        // Abort program execution.
        abort();
    }
}
```

When I compile this, the SRAM usage is 1469 bytes (together with the rest of my sketch and classes).

When I comment the line below, I get a segmentation fault in a random assert call (when I comment out that call, I get it in the next, etc.).

```
    //Serial.println(funcName);
```

When I also comment out the second print statement, the compiler reports only 1137 bytes SRAM usage (which I expect since this was about equal until before I added the Assert class).

```
    //Serial.println(funcName);
    //Serial.println(fileName);
```

Questions:

1. How can I get rid of the segmentation fault?
2. How can it be that about 332 bytes are used for one two additional print statements? (maybe related to the const char* buffering (?)

Comment: the  segmentation fault is a bug in compiler in 1.6.22 and 1.6.23. more here https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=619213.msg4195749#msg4195749

Comment: try `F(__FILE__)` and `F(__func__)`. (change the parameter type to __FlashStringHelper)

Comment: @Juraj Somehow it only works for `__FILE__` but not for `__func__`. Anyway using `F(
__FILE__)` was about -90B difference (It's probably full path and it was only used in one file).

Comment: so the compiler optimizes the parameters away if hey are not used

Comment: Why are you wasting a class on this? Just use the prints directly in the macro.

Comment: @juraj Thanks (see answer, but feel free to add your own if you want an upvote from me)

Comment: @KIIV Thanks (see answer, but feel free to add your own if you want an upvote from me)

Comment: @Majenko Thanks (see answer, but feel free to add your own if you want an upvote from me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, this answer is not MY answer, but approximately the combination of the first 5 comments from my original question.

What I did was:

- (Juraj) Changed the compiler version to 6.21
- (juraj) Added an F in `F(__FILE__)`
- (KIIV) Removed **func**; this did not work with the `F` flash helper, but I can find back the code anyway unambiguously because of the file name + line number.
- (Majenko) I removed the class and use a macro. This costs some more Flash memory (depending on the number of asserts I use, but I'm still around 40% (was 35%).

The SRAM usage is now 1125 bytes, even less than where I'm started with.

The resulting code is below:

```
#define assert(expression) \
  if (!(expression)) \
  { \
    Serial.println(F(__FILE__)); \
    Serial.println(__LINE__, DEC); \
    Serial.flush(); \
    abort(); \
  }
```

Comment: About `class` - in this case it was used as old form of namespaces (as namespaces weren't present in c++ until 1990). However struct was used more likely as it doesn't need `public:` specifier.